# How to parse items from a large JSON stream in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, tree, stream

So I have downloaded the Wikidata JSON dump and it's about 90GB, too large to load into memory. It consists of a simple JSON structure like this:

```
[
  item,
  item,
  item,
  ...
]
```

Each "item" looks something like this:

```
{
  "type": "item",
  "id": "Q23",
  "labels": {
    "<lang>": obj
  },
  "descriptions": {
    "<lang>": {
      "language": "<lang>",
      "value": "<string>"
    },
  },
  "aliases": {
    "<key>": [
      obj,
      obj,
    ],
  },
  "claims": {
    "<keyID>": [
       {
        "mainsnak": {
          "snaktype": "value",
          "property": "<keyID>",
          "datavalue": {
            "value": {
              "entity-type": "<type>",
              "numeric-id": <num>,
              "id": "<id>"
            },
            "type": "wikibase-entityid"
          },
          "datatype": "wikibase-item"
        },
        "type": "statement",
        "id": "<anotherId>",
        "rank": "preferred",
        "references": [
          {
            "hash": "<hash>",
            "snaks": {
              "<keyIDX>": [
                {
                  "snaktype": "value",
                  "property": "P854",
                  "datavalue": obj,
                  "datatype": "url"
                }
              ]
            },
            "snaks-order": [
              "<propID>"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "sitelinks": {
    "<lang>wiki": {
      "site": "<lang>wiki",
      "title": "<string>",
      "badges": []
    }
  }
}
```

The JSON stream is configured like this:

```
const fs   = require('fs')
const zlib = require('zlib')
const { parser } = require('stream-json')

let stream = fs.createReadStream('./wikidata/latest-all.json.gz')
stream
  .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
  .pipe(parser())
  .on('data', buildItem)

function buildItem(data) {
  switch (data.name) {
    case `startArray`:
      break
    case `startObject`:
      break
    case `startKey`:
      break
    case `stringChunk`:
      break
    case `endKey`:
      break
    case `keyValue`:
      break
    case `startString`:
      break
    case `endString`:
      break
    case `stringValue`:
      break
    case `endObject`:
      break
    case `endArray`:
      break
  }
}
```

Notice the `buildItem` has the key information, it shows that the JSON stream emits objects like this (these are the logs):

```
{ name: 'startArray' }
{ name: 'startObject' }
{ name: 'startKey' }
{ name: 'startString' }
{ name: 'stringValue', value: 'type' }
{ name: 'endString' }
...
```

How do you parse this into `item` objects like the above? Parsing this linear stream into a tree is very difficult to comprehend.

A sample of output from the JSON stream is [here](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/4d3a451e7da9effa5862a35265994ad5), which you could use to test a parser if it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Using Built-In Functions (StreamArray)

[`stream-json`](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json) already has built-in functions that converts streams into objects (in this case, you're looking for [StreamArray](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json/wiki/StreamArray)). You may want to use the built-in functions, as they've been coded with performance in mind.

To use it, it'd look something like:

```
const fs   = require('fs')
const zlib = require('zlib')
const { parser } = require('stream-json')
const { streamArray } = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamArray')

let stream = fs.createReadStream('./wikidata/latest-all.json.gz')
stream
  .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
  .pipe(parser())
  .pipe(streamArray())
  .on('data', d => processData(d.value))

function processData(data) {
  console.log(data)
}
```

I recommend taking a look at the wiki at https://github.com/uhop/stream-json/wiki for more information, as it has additional functions, particularly for filtering or transformation, which will probably be useful for you, especially if speed is a concern.

Comment: Cool :) One question, how can I resume at a specific point? I can ask another question for that, here it is, explaining the problem I just ran into haha https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625354/how-to-resume-parsing-a-large-json-stream-at-a-specific-point-in-node-js-with-st.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly you want something like this. I used an `ObjectBuilder` class that combines all methods to build one JSON object.
It uses `parentStack` to keep track of all objects and arrays. When the object/array is started with `startObject/startArray` a new JSON object/array is pushed onto the stack. Once this object/array is completed it is popped off of the stack. The last object that is popped off of the stack is the whole item object and can be processed further (in the example below I just print it out).

The current object or array that is currently being constructed is always on top of the stack.

I had to use a subset of the sample you provided because it did not contain a matching number of `startObject` and `endObject` items, which resulted into an invalid JSON. I included this subset below the code.

Hopefully, this is what you were looking for :)

(Note, I only wrapped `buildItem()` function in `runSample()` function so that I can include the sample JSON at the bottom to make it look neater in this online editor. You can move `buildItem()` function outside.)

```js
class ObjectBuilder {
    constructor() {
        this.finalObject = undefined;
        this.parentStack = [];

        this.currentKey = undefined;
    }

    hasFinished() {
        return this.finalObject !== undefined;
    }

    getFinalObject() {
        return this.finalObject;
    }

    currentObject() {
        return this.parentStack[this.parentStack.length - 1];
    }

    addValue(val) {
        if (Array.isArray(this.currentObject())) {
            this.currentObject().push(val);
        }
        else {
            this.currentObject()[this.currentKey] = val;
            this.currentKey = undefined;
        }
    }

    processData(data) {
        switch (data.name) {
            case `startKey`:
            case `endKey`:
            case `startString`:
            case `endString`:
            case `stringChunk`:
                // ignore, always followed by [something]Value
                break;

            case `keyValue`:
                this.currentObject()[data.value] = undefined;
                this.currentKey = data.value;
                break;
            case `numberValue`:
                this.addValue(Number(data.value))
                break
            case `stringValue`:
                this.addValue(data.value);
                break;

            case `startObject`:
                let newObject = {};
                if (this.parentStack.length === 0) {
                    // do nothing else, initialises first parent
                }
                else if (Array.isArray(this.currentObject())) {
                    this.currentObject().push(newObject);
                }
                else {
                    this.currentObject()[this.currentKey] = newObject;
                }
                this.parentStack.push(newObject);
                this.currentKey = undefined;
                break;

            case `endObject`:
                let parent = this.parentStack.pop();
                if (this.parentStack.length === 0) {
                    this.finalObject = parent;
                }
                break;

            case `startArray`:
                let newArray = [];
                if (Array.isArray(this.currentObject())) {
                    this.currentObject().push(newArray);
                }
                else {
                    this.currentObject()[this.currentKey] = newArray;
                }
                this.parentStack.push(newArray);
                this.currentKey = undefined;

                break;
            case `endArray`:
                this.parentStack.pop();
                this.currentKey = undefined;
                break;
        }
    }
}

function runSample(streamData) {

    let currentlyProcessing = undefined;
    function buildItem(data) {
        if (currentlyProcessing === undefined && data.name === "endArray") {
            return; // stream ended
        }

        if (currentlyProcessing === undefined) {
            currentlyProcessing = new ObjectBuilder();
        }
        currentlyProcessing.processData(data);

        if (currentlyProcessing.hasFinished()) {
            // Finished building project; do something with it
            let niceOutput = JSON.stringify(currentlyProcessing.getFinalObject(), null, 4);
            console.log(niceOutput);
            currentlyProcessing = undefined;
        }
    }


    // simulate reading stream
    for (let i = 0; i < streamData.length; ++i) {
        if (i === 0) {
            // Skip first chunk as it starts the array of items
            continue;
        }
        buildItem(streamData[i]);
    }
}

const streamData = [{"name": "startArray"},{"name": "startObject"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "type"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "type"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "item"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "item"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "id"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "id"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "Q31"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "Q31"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "labels"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "labels"},{"name": "startObject"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "el"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "el"},{"name": "startObject"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "language"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "language"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "el"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "el"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "value"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "value"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "Β"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "έ"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "λ"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "γ"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ι"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ο"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "Βέλγιο"},{"name": "endObject"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ay"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "ay"},{"name": "startObject"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "language"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "language"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ay"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "ay"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "value"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "value"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "Bilkiya"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "Bilkiya"},{"name": "endObject"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "pnb"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "pnb"},{"name": "startObject"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "language"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "language"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "pnb"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "pnb"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "value"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "value"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ب"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ی"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ل"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ج"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ی"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "م"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "بیلجیم"},{"name": "endObject"},{"name": "endObject"},{"name": "endObject"},{"name": "startObject"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "type"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "type"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "item"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "item"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "id"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "id"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "Q31"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "Q31"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "labels"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "labels"},{"name": "startObject"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "el"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "el"},{"name": "startObject"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "language"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "language"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "el"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "el"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "value"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "value"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "Β"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "έ"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "λ"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "γ"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ι"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ο"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "Βέλγιο"},{"name": "endObject"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ay"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "ay"},{"name": "startObject"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "language"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "language"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ay"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "ay"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "value"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "value"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "Bilkiya"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "Bilkiya"},{"name": "endObject"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "pnb"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "pnb"},{"name": "startObject"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "language"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "language"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "pnb"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "pnb"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "value"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "value"},{"name": "startString"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ب"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ی"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ل"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ج"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "ی"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "م"},{"name": "endString"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "بیلجیم"},{"name": "endObject"},{"name": "startKey"},{"name": "stringChunk","value": "nestedArray"},{"name": "endKey"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "nestedArray"},{"name": "startArray"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "a"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "b"},{"name": "startArray"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "c"},{"name": "startObject"},{"name": "keyValue","value": "another object"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "d"},{"name": "endObject"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "e"},{"name": "endArray"},{"name": "stringValue","value": "b"},{"name": "endArray"},{"name": "endObject"},{"name": "endObject"},{"name": "endArray"}];

runSample(streamData);
```

Comment: Oh wow this looks amazing! It is a bit over my head so give me some time to take a deeper look to get an understanding.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you want me to describe it more in-depth. It's not as complicated as it might look :)

Comment: How can you make it work if you don't know the size of the stream, so it doesn't fail on the last one? Right now it's using _"Skip first and last chunk as it starts and ends the array of items"_. How do you remove that requirement so we can make it work on an unknown length stream (i.e. I don't know how many "item" objects there are in this gzipped JSON file haha)?

Comment: Also I notice this `this.isArray = true` seems to only allow for one layer of arrays, I'm not sure tho. What happens if you have objects with property values that are arrays, and/or deeply nested arrays? Does it work with that? If not, how would it be modified to work with that?

Comment: Yeah it's not working for me on the actual stream data unfortunately. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at this.currentObject()[this.currentKey].push(val)`. Seems somehow the stack needs to include the current key and such. Basically that `currentKey` and `isArray` need to be more dynamic to include nested values.

Comment: Ah apologies, I forgot about nested arrays. I will fix it asap.

Comment: @LancePollard I have updated the code and the sample. It should work now with nested arrays as well as stop correctly for streams of any length.