# How to resume parsing a large JSON stream at a specific point in Node.js with stream-json package?

Tags: node.js, json, stream, pipe

I'm so happy to have been shown how to actually parse JSON objects out of an extremely large JSON file using the [stream-json](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json) module. It was a pretty simple and straightforward built-in method [it turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64580743/how-to-parse-items-from-a-large-json-stream-in-javascript/64618548#64618548)!

However, looking at the [Wiki](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json/wiki) of stream-json, I don't see a way to **resume** processing at a specific object index. How can I do that? Or more generally if there's no quick way to do that, how can I resume at a specific place in the plain JSON stream or just plain gzipped string stream?

For background, I am parsing the [Wikidata JSON dump](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/entities/) which is about 90GB. I was doing an initial round of parsing through the dump [items](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/DataModel/JSON) to collect the classes of each entity/item, but then my parser crashed because of some unexpected data structure **760,000** items into the process!!! Who knows how many items there actually are haha. But I have restarted the process, this time with a try catch to skip over bad data. I forgot to time it initially, but timing it this time around it is taking on average **4 seconds per 1000 items** to parse this JSON stream. So 4s * 760 = 3040s is about **50 minutes** to get back to where I left off. That is a long time to wait, especially since I am going to have to do 5 or 10 rounds of parsing as I uncover new things I want to retrieve from this data. So I would like to know how to jump to the point where it crashes or where I left off, if at all possible.

How can I do that with [stream-json](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json)? Perhaps there is a way to rework the [StreamArray](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json/blob/master/streamers/StreamArray.js) code to support jumping to a specific item. Or perhaps I can somehow associate the raw `wikidata/latest-all.json.gz` gzip string stream to the stream-json, so I can point to some location in the `latest-all.json.gz` string where the `fs.createReadStream` should start reading from? Something like that.

Would love to know how to **resume** at some specific place. How can I do that in this case?

My current code is essentially this:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const zlib = require('zlib')
const { parser } = require('stream-json')
const { streamArray } = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamArray')

let input = fs.createReadStream(`./wikidata/latest-all.json.gz`)

input
  .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
  .pipe(parser())
  .pipe(streamArray())
  .on('data', d => handle(d.value))

function handle(object) {
  // each entity in the json stream
}
```

For context on where I'm coming from, I am thinking along the same lines as [resuming a wget download with the `-c` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165875/resume-failed-download-using-linux-command-line-tool/165881#165881). If your internet cuts out with wget downloading a 100GB file, or a set of 10,000 files, you can just do `wget -c <url>` essentially and continue where you left off, rather than having to re-download everything. I would like to do that equivalent sort of thing with the JSON stream parser. To skip all the entities I have already parsed before it crashed or the program exited.

If there is no straightforward way to do this, what sort of hack could I use?

*Actually, the first few thousand items took 4 seconds each, now it looks like they are taking 0.5-1s each as we move into the later data in the stream, so after 30 minutes I am at item 1,271,000. Slightly better, but still a long wait.*

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to efficiently resume from a stream using stream-json [from reading the creator's comments](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json/issues/38). If you're working with such large files, I'd recommend to either put it in a database or to split it up into smaller files, to make the data more manageable. If you do want to pursue resuming from a location, you might have some more luck using the JSONL format-- from then, you just have to know what line number to skip to.